# Declaring a static function of class as a friend

Tags: c++, friend

My question arises because, from my understanding, you must forward declare or define functions before declaring them as friends. Is the following valid?

```
template <typename> class class1;

template <typename T>
class class2 {
    ...
    friend void class1<T>::foo();
    ...
}

template <typename T>
class class1 {
    ...
    static void foo() {}
    ...
}
```

The problem here is that you can't forward declare the static function `foo`. Hopefully this encapsulated everything necessary for this question. I tried something like this and it compiled and worked fine, but I was wondering if this is still considered valid since I also read some compilers accept friend declarations without previous forward declarations although this is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Like it or not, declaring something as friend creates forward declaration outside of the class. This is explicitly written in the standard and compilers support this.

Your example is more complicated. You are trying to use something from inside of the forward declaration. Well, smart compiler may handle this. All compilers - I am not so sure. Second point - your friend declaration is inside the template. Compilers parse templates only partially. They cannot do it better. All substitutions and checks happen only when the template is instantiated. At this point the compiler knows much more. In your sample `class2` is never instantiated.

Try to write something weird inside the template and you will find that this will compile. Then add instantiation without changing the template itself. Compiler will give you errors.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted what I read about forward declarations and friends. C++ primer states `Some compilers allow calls to a friend function when there is no ordinary declaration for that function. Even if your compiler allows such calls, it is a good idea to provide a separate declarations for friends`. I think I interpreted this to mean a forward declaration must be present for a function **before** it is declared as a friend, but it actually means that for users of the class to call that function a declaration must be present, so it could actually be present after the class definition?

Comment: You can place identical forward declarations multiple times everywhere. Friend creates one. If it is already existing or not - this does not matter. Creation of separate forward declarations is a question of style. I would recommend doing that, but just for clarity and readability. This will not change the meaning of the code.